# Работа с двумерным массивом больших чисел

Tags: c++

Подключил библиотеку boost. Работаю с массивом так:

```
mp::cpp_int **mas = new mp::cpp_int *[n.convert_to<size_t>()];
for (mp::cpp_int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        mas[i] = new mp::cpp_int[n.convert_to<size_t>())];
```

Когда счетчиком for прохожу, он ругается:

```
отсутствует оператор "[]", соответствующий этим операндам
```

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так, раз уж вы взялись везде ставить `convert_to<size_t>()`, то тогда должно, наверное, быть

```
mas[i.convert_to<size_t>()] = new mp::cpp_int[n.convert_to<size_t>()];
```